# How to keep a partial on the same page after form errors?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my `Business` model, when I try to create a business and an error occurs, I noticed after the POST it gets rid of my `shared/page_header` partial:

```
def page_title
  "#{@page_title}"
end

<% unless @page_title.blank? %>
<div class="row">
   <div class="page-header span12">
      <h1><%= @page_title %></h1>
   </div>
</div>
<% end %>

def new
  @business = Business.new
  @page_title = "Add Business"
end

def create
  @business = Business.new(params[:business])
  if @business.save
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "This Business was successfully added."
  else
    render :new, :notice => "It seems there was an error. Please try again."
  end
end
```

Now I notice I start on `/businesses/new` but after the POST it goes to `/businesses`. Someone told me this was normal, but I never seen this type of behavior until now. If it helps, the `new` and `create` actions are the only ones in my `Business` resource. What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add @page_title = "Add Business" to your create method. "render :new" renders the new template but not executes the new method.

> Using render with :action is a frequent source of confusion for Rails newcomers. The specified action is used to determine which view to render, but Rails does not run any of the code for that action in the controller. Any instance variables that you require in the view must be set up in the current action before calling render. from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: Woah, Simple enough. I didn't know actions like `create` could be used in this way. I'll keep this in mind. Thank you.